# How to set multiple AlarmManagers?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I have an app that needs to set alarms for multiple days of the week, depending on what days the user sets them. I have it working where it triggers an alarm at the appropriate time, but am wanting to know how to do multiple without them overridding the current AlarmManager. For example, here is my test code:

```
final int alarmid = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();    //creates unique id for the alarm attached to the object
tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i).setAlarmId(alarmid);
for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if(tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i).returnDays()[j])   //if this day of the week has an alarm
            {
                int adjustedday = j+2;  //makes time for DAY_OF_WEEK where sunday = 1, monday = 2, etc.
                if (adjustedday == 8)
                    adjustedday = 1;



                Calendar startcal = Calendar.getInstance();
                startcal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, adjustedday);
                startcal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i).returnTimes()[0]);
                startcal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i).returnTimes()[1]);
                startcal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                Log.i("mydebug","Starting cal day of week: " + adjustedday);
                Log.i("mydebug","Starting cal hour of day: " + tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i).returnTimes()[0]);
                Log.i("mydebug","Starting minute: " + tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i).returnTimes()[1]);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SilenceHandler.class);
                intent.putExtra("starttime",tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i));
                intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "Test!");  //FOR TESTING
                PendingIntent pendintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarmid, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmman = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmman.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startcal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendintent);
//              startcal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.returnSchedule(i).returnTimes()[1])+1);
//              alarmman.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startcal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendintent);
            }
        }
```

The for loop iterates through days of the week, and at each iteration checks to see if the alarm should be set for that day. This code works (presumably), but to test if I could set another alarm on top of it I added in the last two lines of code that are commented out here. This makes the alarm go off a minute later, but not a minute earlier as well. I am doing this to demonstrate that if I want this code to work for multiple days of the week, the way the code is currently set up will just have the alarm set for the last day of the week that returns true. How can I make multiple alarms?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that although you are creating a unique ID for your `PendingIntent`, which would set separate alarms, in your test you are reusing the same `PendingIntent`, which would override your previous one. Create a new `PendingIntent` with a different `alarmid` to test this.